# SQL query with LEFT JOIN returning no results

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 MySQL tables `IM_Transfer` and `IM_INV`. I run the following query regularly:

```
SELECT
    `IM_Transfer`.`sku`,
    `IM_Transfer`.`vendor_sku`,
    `IM_Transfer`.`Description`,
    `IM_Transfer`.`Receiver`,
    `IM_INV`.`LOC_ID`, 
    `IM_INV`.`QTY_ON_HND` 
FROM 
    `IM_Transfer` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `IM_INV` 
ON 
    `IM_Transfer`.`sku` = `IM_INV`.`ITEM_NO` 
WHERE `LOC_ID` = "AF" 
    OR `LOC_ID` = "LO" 
    OR `LOC_ID` = "S" 
    OR `LOC_ID` = "SL" 
ORDER BY 
    `IM_Transfer`.`sku`, 
    `IM_INV`.`LOC_ID` 
    ASC
```

Most of the time, most of the lines in `IM_Transfer` match by `IM_Transfer`.`sku` and `IM_INV`.`ITEM_NO` and the ones that don't come back with `null` values in the last 2 columns.

I just ran this query with a a single row in `IM_Transfer` and it does not have any matching data in `IM_INV`. How do I update the query to still return a row with just `null` in the `LOC_ID` and `QTY_ON_HND` columns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be careful when tagging. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: The problem here is because you have turned your left join into an inner join with your where clause. You should get in the habit of always specifying the table when you reference columns.

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: Your where selects on values from `im_inv`. So if there is one line in the other table that's not matched it will return nothing.

Comment: @SeanLange I see and that makes perfect sense. I am still learning and appreciate your clarification on that.

Comment: Would it work if I added IM_Transfer.Receiver > 0 to the where clause?

Comment: Adding IM_Transfer.Receiver > 0 to the where clause fixed it. You guys are wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause only evaluates to true when there is a row in the outer joined table.  Referencing a column from the outer joined table in a where clause usually makes the join into an inner join.

I think that the query that you want is:

```
SELECT
  `IM_Transfer`.`sku`,
  `IM_Transfer`.`vendor_sku`,
  `IM_Transfer`.`Description`,
  `IM_Transfer`.`Receiver`,
  `IM_INV`.`LOC_ID`, 
  `IM_INV`.`QTY_ON_HND` 
FROM 
  `IM_Transfer` 
LEFT JOIN 
  `IM_INV` 
ON 
`IM_Transfer`.`sku` = `IM_INV`.`ITEM_NO` 
 AND ( `LOC_ID` = "AF" 
  OR `LOC_ID` = "LO" 
  OR `LOC_ID` = "S" 
  OR `LOC_ID` = "SL" ) 
ORDER BY 
  `IM_Transfer`.`sku`, 
  `IM_INV`.`LOC_ID` 
ASC
```

Notes:

1. ASC is the default sort order, so it doesn't need to be specified.
2. Your LOC_ID filter is simpler when expressed as  `LOC_ID IN ("AF","LO","S","SL")`

Thanks @SeanLange for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This did it. I know I still have a ways to go when it comes to understanding SQL. Thanks